# How can I check that my Android app is not tampered with during runtime?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dump, unpack, anti-cheat

I'm a Unity Game Developer, and I develop games on Android. However, recently, my game has been experiencing cheating issues, so I want to check the signature of the Android app to see if users are modifying my game. When I attempt to retrieve the signature using this code:

signatures = packageInfo.Get("signingInfo").Call<AndroidJavaObject[]>("getApkContentsSigners");

, I find that even if I modify the libunity.so file within the APK, the signature is still obtained. However, when I try the command keytool -printcert -jarfile your_app.apk, it indicates that my APK has been modified regarding the libunity.so file. Is there any way to check the signature during runtime that would detect modifications similar to the keytool method?

I hope to be able to detect file modifications within the Android app during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The [Play integrity and signing services](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity) might be what you need